# I want to save a Selected Option in a Swift UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

so I have a UIPicker view. Now I have something selected now with that I want to save that selection so that the next time I go back to that page the same option that I selected is still there. right now it just goes to the first option selected which is grams.

Thx I'm new to Swift

Here is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

var measurementTypes = ["Grams","Ounces", "Pounds"]


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return measurementTypes.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return measurementTypes[row]
}


// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selected = measurementTypes[row]
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save the selected row number in `UserDefaults` so that it can be accessed next time.

```
// Capture the picker view selection
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selected = measurementTypes[row]
    // Save selected row integer in User Defaults
    UserDefaults.standard.set(row, forKey: "pickerViewRow")
}
```

Then, in `override func viewDidLoad()` you can retrieve this value and set the picker view:

```
let row = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pickerViewRow")
pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: False)
```

Comment: Thanks @Moritz - I will edit the answer. I had heard it wasn’t strictly necessary but was unaware that it could cause issues.

Comment: The main issue is that it forces UserDefault to *wait* synchronously that all transactions are finished before allowing new ones. So not only it doesn’t “force save” anything but it can prevent stuff being saved or loaded in time.

Comment: @Moritz Thanks for that.